# How to target dynamic generated text boxes using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a `TextBox` that gets generated in a `GridView` dynamically. When you inspect the page the `TextBox` looks like this below.  I am trying to find a way to target this `TextBox` and all other `TextBoxes` in this `GridView` so that i can run a script against them. I am having a lot of trouble finding a way of being able to target this text box.  I tried setting a style class to the `GridView` and call on that but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$controlProductsList1$gvItems$ctl04$Option-30482_e0edc10a-7dba-40d0-a4f1-7c4c5801c0ca" type="text" id="MainContent_controlProductsList1_gvItems_Option-30482_e0edc10a-7dba-40d0-a4f1-7c4c5801c0ca_2">
```

What is the best way using javascript to target the TextBoxes that are dynamically generated in a GridView?

Can you give the gridview a class and call on that class alone?

This is the script that will need to target the inputs

```
$('#inputID').keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Comment: @Sam What would be the difference? Still have to target the textbox right? Maybe you can elaborate. I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: He already uses jQuery, according to `$('#inputID').keyup`

Comment: sorry my bad. I was going to say have you tried to get it with ClientID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you appear to be using jQuery, check out your options on the [JQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page. One option is to use a generic [input selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) like:

```
$("#<%=gvItems.ClientID%> :input").keyup(function(){
      this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

The code above assumes your control is called gvItems and will render the client ID of the grid view for use in the JQuery ID selector (#MainContent_controlProductsList1_gvItems...) and find all input child elements (:input).

Another option would be to put a class directly on the input controls:

```
$(".inputClass").keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the idea could be put a css  class on the textbox. If it is generated by your code dynamically.
And then use class selector in your jQuery.

```
  $('.inputcss').keyup(function(){
               this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
   });
```

Or even you can use `id` of the gridview and find input:text inside the gridview and use your function. Below is a sample code

```
 $('#<%=grid.ClientID%>')
 .find('tr')
 .each(function(row) {
      $(this).find('input')
            .each(function(col) {
                      $(this).keyup(function(){
               this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
                  });

                  } 
             });
  });

});
```

### Edit 1

And if you only want to show in upper case you can use css as follows

```
 h1 {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

More details

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: Agreed, classes usage is most easy way to find server control on client.